# Formatting Values in Razor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app that uses Razor as the view engine. I am trying

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="price">Price</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
    <input id="price" name="price" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.Price.ToString("G")" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When this code runs, I get an error that says:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

If I replace `@Model.Price.ToString("G")` with just `@Model.Price`, my app works. However, the decimal value is not formatted properly. The Price variable comes from my controller action. In the controller, I have:

```
public ActionResult View(int? id)
{
  Product product = null;
  if (id.HasValue)
    product = Product.LoadFromDb(id.Value);
  else
    product = new Product();

  // product.Price is a nullable decimal (i.e. decimal?)

  return View(product);
}
```

How do I format the Price in my view to be up to two decimal places?

Thanks!

Comment: No it is quoted properly, razor handles that.

Comment: Are you sure it's not null? Try `@Model.Price.Value.ToString("G")` maybe?

Comment: @Phaeze correct, my mistake.

Comment: I wouldn't format the string on the view, I believe it should be done server side, so when the view gets the data it is formatted properly already

Comment: One day, we'll all be able to use `@Model.Price?.ToString("G")` :D

Comment: But for now `@string.Format("{0:G}", Model.Price)` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is nullable then you will need Value `@Model.Price.Value.ToString("G")` that will work but bear in mind to check `HasValue`.

To be honest in my opinion you should do formatting on server side.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem here is that it is a nullable.

PoweredByOrange's suggestion in the comment should be correct but I would recommend also adding a null check or you'll just run into a different exception, something like this:

```
value="@(Model.Price.HasValue ? Model.Price.Value.ToString("G") : "$0.00")"
```